# Switch the name of the file

Tags: java

I have file names like 323423233.

I want to add the last 2 digits of the file name and add it to the front and
make it 33/323423233 and add extension to it(like .doc).

What's a simple statement that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a slash in the file name? :)

Comment: Which File System supports `/` in the filename? Anyway, look at the `java.io.File` class.

Comment: Does it have to be java? Shell scripting is more suited for this type of task.

Comment: Could you paste the code whatever you tried?

Comment: @SJuan76 NOT! This is 2013, use `Files` and `Path`

Comment: What system are you on and what tools are you using? It must be pretty strange to support a '/' in the filename - I can't guess what platform you are talking about.

Comment: Yea it has to be java. It's the requirement to put /.

Comment: @DMac - He probably wants to create directories as well.  Obviously the OP has done a poor job of specifying his requirements (as well as researching how to implement them).

Comment: Guess: OP wants to _create directory `33`_ and put the file under that directory

Comment: "It's going inside database so / has to be used" <-- eh? Sorry, but I fail to see the relationship here

Comment: Do you actually want to create the new file (and validate that it can be done) or are you simply interested in manipulating the name of the file as a string?  You need to be **WAY** more specific about what you want.  This question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: I must disagree as to whether this question is answered by the quoted post. The quoted post does not use Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is 2013. This is Java 7. This is the time for `Files` and `Path`.

Base directory:

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("/path/to/baseDir");
```

Determine subdirectory for a file:

```
final String s = name.substring(name.length() - 2, name.length());
```

Create that directory:

```
final Path subDir = baseDir.resolve(s);
// Will not do anything if directory already exists...
// But will throw exception if unable to create
Files.createDirectories(subDir);
```

Write to the file:

```
final Path dst = subDir.resolve(name + ".doc");
Files.copy(src, dst);
```

Remove original:

```
Files.delete(src);
```

Or in one operation:

```
Files.move(src, dst);
```